# how to write and sort text from one file to another

Tags: python

I have to produce another text file and group the race results according to their associated organization. My question is since the file is already open, can i just go ahead and start sorting the runners? How do I go about sorting them into groups based on their different associated organization?

```
def get_sec(time_str):
    h, m = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60  # CHANGES the minutes to seconds

with open("~/Desktop/Race_Results_Sample.txt", "r")as myList:
    myList = myList.read()  # reads from list
    myList = [l.split(",") for l in myList.splitlines()]
    myList = sorted(myList, key=lambda kv: kv[1])
    for line in myList:
        num, last, org, time = line
        place = []
        place.append(time)
        placenum = enumerate(sorted(place))
        print(place, placenum)

    for rank, value in enumerate(sorted(place)):
        print(rank, value)

    for line in myList:
        num, last, org, time = line
        new_time = get_sec(time)
        mile = round((((new_time/ 3.10686)/60)/60), 3)
        mile = str(mile)
        print ('{:<20s}{:<5s}{:<5s}{:<7s}{:<10s}'.format(last, num, org, time, mile))

     lines = myList.readlines()
```

Comment: Doing these operations manually on files is prone to errors and is time consuming. I would suggest spending some time on learning a library like pandas, which makes operating with data much easier and also has a quite small learning curve.

Comment: that is not an option for me... :( do you know how i can go about this?